# Data Importing Error in Migrated MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have a situation in Migrated (4.0 to 5.0) Microsoft CRM 2011 in which data importing associated

The issue is - I am successfully migrated Microsoft CRM 2011 from Microsoft CRM 4.0 through Deployment Manager. After importing, all entities are working fine. Then I import some data (csv file, 3 KB) into Lead Entity but after importing the import wizard window will appear on submitted message without any success messages or failure messages.

Please give me your ideas and suggestions on this.

Shown in the screenshots below:

[image]
after Data importing, the lead entity is empty
[image]

---

It's not a problem of views or any filters, I've checked. The issue is:

I am trying to import data from csv file to migrated dynamics crm 2011 using the import facility in data management section. I have created mappings and have uploaded the data file. Looks like the the job has not yet started to upload the data from csv files yet because:
Status Reason = Submitted (not completed or anything else) Success = 0 Errors = 0 Total Count = 0
And it shows the import job under the view of "Not Started Imports".

I just want to know how can I make the process start?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something with your view.  You can perform an advanced find (or use the stunnware tools) to query the Leads.  Make sure you don't have any filter to verify the data and then compare the retrieved fields to your "All Leads" view.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the above mentioned issue. The problem was solved when I re-install &       re-configure the CRM Database.

Thanks

prajosh

Answer (score 0):

This is usually happened for me.
What i have done is Restart CRM Async service.Most of the time it worked.If it is in the production you might have issue.

This is the command to restart theCRM Async service

**net stop MSCRMAsyncService**

**net start MSCRMAsyncService**